# Is there an array-like data structure in the Haskell libraries that is O(log n) to insert and O(log n) to retrieve? Can I derive one using zippers?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, time-complexity

I am surprised to find that `Array`, for example, rebuilds the whole data structure whenever a change occurs, taking O(n).

I'd expect someone to have already implemented a Zipper Array (or zipper vector) that is pure and has O(log n) queries and O(log n) insert.

Does such implementation already exist? My searches (for Zipper Array and Zipper Vector) yielded no such library.

If not, is there a way to automatically derive a zipper from the already existent array and or vector?

Worst case scenario, I might try to build one myself, but I'd have to brush up on red black trees (and see if zippers work well with them!)

---

EDIT: Indeed O(1) would not work with trees, as noted in comments

Comment: Is a zipper array related to huet zipper?  I'm not seeing how you can use a red black tree to give O(1) insert and query in an immutable array, a link would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an exact match for what you're proposing, but there is the *skew binomial random access list*, which supports appending a value in time O(log n) and editing of values at arbitrary positions in time O(log n). Would that work for you?

Comment: No tree-based structure is going to give you O(1) queries and O(1) insert anywhere except the immediate zipper pointer, and you're going to have to pay O(log n) somewhere -- if not on inserts, then on moving back and forth in the tree.

Comment: To be clear -- Vector won't be any better; any updates are going to cost O(n) at some point in some operation.  An example structure, that pays the price in the _old_ versions of the structure, is [Data.Array.Diff](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Array-Diff.html).

Comment: I'm not sure "zipper" and "array-like" go together very well? The standard zipper on lists gives you O(1) read/write to the focus element, O(1) to insert before/after the focus, and O(m) to move the focus m distance from your current position. But wouldn't a zipper built from arrays just have to rebuild the entire array to move the focus or insert? The only thing it would gain you over a non-zipper array would be O(1) write access to the focus (but only after an O(n) operation to choose the focus).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Finger trees](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) have O(log n) insert and query.